# RegionBinarize distance parameter has no effect

Tags: image-processing, segmentation

I'm trying to segment an object from background in noisy micro CT data. The original 3D volume data looks like this:

```
theimg = Image3D[vol, "Real", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale", 
 ColorFunction -> "XRay", Background -> Black]
```

(where `vol` is a 3D matrix imported from a MATLAB file)
[image: original 3D volume]

```
ImageDimensions[theimg]
{73, 72, 75}
```

I first erode away the noise to obtain a seed volume that is within the object of interest:

```
marker = Binarize[DeleteSmallComponents[Erosion[theimg, 8]]]
```

[image: seed volume]

(I have also tried using the following for the seed region:)

```
marker = ImageMultiply[theimg, Binarize[DeleteSmallComponents[Erosion[theimg, 8]]]]
```

---

If I use the default `MeanEuclidean` method for `RegionBinarize` to try to segment the whole object from the background by region growing, the distance parameter seems to have no effect whatsoever on the result, regardless of whether or not I include the optional intensity interval parameter. This does not appear to match the description given in the documentation for `RegionBinarize`. Is this some kind of bug or have I misunderstood how this function is supposed to work? What am I doing wrong?

```
RegionBinarize[theimg, marker, 1*^-100, Method -> "MeanEuclidean"]
```

[image: MeanEuclidean method with tiny distance]

```
RegionBinarize[theimg, marker, 1*^100, Method -> "MeanEuclidean"]
```

[image: MeanEuclidean method with huge distance]

```
RegionBinarize[theimg, marker, 1*^100, {0, 1000}, Method -> "MeanEuclidean"]
```

produces the same result, even though I know there are plenty of voxels adjacent to the seed volume with values in the range of 0 to 1000 HU.

---

When properly segmented, the object should look something like this (the best segmentation I have found thus far):

[image: What a good segmentation looks like]

Comment: In case it matters, I am using Mathematica version 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured out what the problem was. The `MeanEuclidean` method of `RegionBinarize` was unresponsive to changes in the distance parameter because it expects `ImageData` for the image and the marker to be in the range {0, 1}. The actual range for computed tomography data in HU is roughly {-1000, 3000}.

Expected results are obtained by scaling the `ImageData` range to {0, 1} with `ImageAdjust` as a preprocessing step:

`RegionBinarize[ImageAdjust[theimg], marker, distance, Method->"MeanEuclidean"]`